# Client classes from WSDL generating classes differently for different environment with wsimport

Tags: spring-boot, wsdl, pom.xml, wsimport

I have a code which is compiled in the local and feature branch, but it is failing to compile in master branch. When I look into the problem, I found, that the classes generating from WSDL are not the same in feature and master branches.

What am I missing?

pom.xml is:

[image: this is the configuration used in Pom file]

Comment: Please share the error details too.

Comment: I do get the compilation error which is not constant.. I tried by removing the xautonameresolution but got error as “use a class customisation to resolve file generating conflicts”.. I looked into stackoverflow I could find a solution to use binding files.. but I am not getting how to use